# Conditionally use docker agent or different agentLabel based on user choice in jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to be able to use an AWS node to run our jenkins build stages or one of our PCs connected to hardware that can also test the systems. We have some PCs installed that have a recognised agent, and for the AWS node I want to run the steps in a docker container.

Based on this, I would like to decide whether to use the docker agent or the custom agent based on parameters passed in by the user at build time. My jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('customLib')
import groovy.transform.Field
pipeline {
    agent none 
    parameters{
        choice(name: 'NODE', choices: ['PC1', 'PC2', 'dockerNode', 'auto'], description: 'Select which node to run on? Select auto for auto assignment.')
    }
       stages {
        stage('Initialise build environment'){
            agent {  // agent
                docker {
                    image 'docker-image'
                    label 'docker-agent'
                    registryUrl 'url'
                    registryCredentialsId 'dockerRegistry'
                    args '--entrypoint=\'\''
                    alwaysPull true
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.NODE != 'auto' && params.NODE != 'dockerNode'){
                        agentLabel = params.NODE + ' && ' + 'custom_string' // this will lead to running the stages on our PCs
                    }else {
                        agentLabel = 'docker-agent'
                    }
                    env.NODE = params.NODE
                }
            }
        } // initialise build environment

        stage('Waiting for available node') {
            agent {label agentLabel} // if auto or AWSNode is chosen, I want to run in the docker container defined above; otherwise, use the PC.
            post { cleanup { cleanWs() } }
            stages {
                stage('Import and Build project') {
                     steps {
                        script {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                } // Build project
                ...
            }
        } // Waiting for available node
    }
}
```

Assuming the PC option works fine if I don't add this docker option and the docker option also works fine on its own, how do I add a label to my custom docker agent and use it conditionally like above? Running this Jenkinsfile, I get the message `'There are no nodes with the label ‘docker-agent’` which seems to say that it can't find the label I defined.

Edit: I worked around this problem by adding two stages that run a when block that decides whether the stage runs or not, with a different agent.
Pros: I'm able to choose where the steps are run.

Cons:

1. The inside build and archive stages are identical, so they are simply repeated for each outer stage. (This may become a pro if I want to run a separate HW test stage only on one of the agents)
2. both outer stages always run, and that means that the docker container is always pulled from the registry, even if it is not used (i.e. if we choose to run the build process on a PC)

Seems like stages do not lend themselves easily to being encapsulated into functions.